# Django: Define URL for media file

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I would like to define a custom URL to a folder of files, that can be managed by ftp (I will grant ftp access to this folder 'repository').

e.g.

```
File on disk:
var/www/djangoproject/media/repository/logo.png
```

I want this image to have the URL:

```
/abc/def/logo.png
```

And for other files in the folder respectively.
Is this possible in urls.py ?

Comment: You can have whatever url you like, this is a task for a view to retrieve the file

Comment: Well, not the view, but the static webserver configuration. This has nothing to do with urls.py, either way.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in `urls.py` in a variety of ways. However Django usually doesn't serve static files from Django itself.

Comment: I am aware that this is not the normal ways static content is served. I have a standard static content setup. But circumstances with my customer require a n additional solution for some files like this.

Comment: @Antti: Could you help me with a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ordinary view as you would do with any other view; then in that view, redirect to the actual URL.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    return redirect('/media/repository/logo.png')
```

Use `permanent=True` to make browsers cache the other URL *permanently*:

```
return redirect('/media/repository/logo.png', permanent=True)
```

Note that it is **impossible** for a server to force the client to forget a permanent redirect.

Comment: Nice. So simple. I was so focused that it must be done in urls.py :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is possible in `urls.py` and `views.py`. However, using a web server (e.g. nginx) to [serve static content](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) is apparently a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. And static file serving is used as described in Django documentation on my site. But I have a special situation here. Thats why I need a solution this way.

Comment: If you're using a static server then you might as well configure that server to make the exception for you.